# How do I solve this differential equation with the initial conditions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Solve the differential equation $f′′(x)= sin(x)+cos(x)$ with the initial conditions $f′(π)=2$ and $f(0)=π$.

This is on my homework but I've never seen anything like it and it's due on Monday, and we never went over something like this. I tried looking for a similar  problem but can't find any, at least that I understand.

Am I supposed to find the original function $f(x)$?

Comment: Last part of your question? Yes,now what is the anti derivative of a sine and a cosine? Have you learned that?

Comment: No; I don't even know what an antiderivative is. Is that supposed to be what gets me sine? Would it be -cos since that would be -(-sine)?

Comment: If you have not learned what an anti derivative is, then your question is a pretty "advanced" question. In essence, you need to anti derive twice (and there are some constants to deal with). Yes, the anti derivative of the sine is the negative cosine and the anti derivative of the cosine is the sine.

Comment: I don't even know why they put this on our homework honestly. I checked the syllabus and this is a section we learn in 2 weeks. So wouldn't that make then $f'(x)=-cos(x)+sin(x)$? I tried to put a $pi$ but it didn't equal 2.

Comment: @JozemiteApps remember the constant of integration; with it, you'd get $f'(x)=-cos(x)+sin(x)+C$ and here you can use the initial condition to find $C$.

Comment: @JozemiteApps. After Coldnumber's suggestion you can anti derive again (you will get 2 trig terms AND a linear term) and use the other initial condition to find the second Constant.

Comment: P. S. You used the anti derivative all the time in integral calculus: if $F'(x)=f(x)$ we say that the anti derivative of $f$ is $F$.

Comment: So does that mean $f'(x)=-cos(x)+sin(x)+C$ and solving for $f'(\pi) = 2$ so $C=1$?

Comment: @JozemiteApps, that is correct.

Comment: So the antiderivative of $f'(x)$ is $f(x)=-sin(x)-cos(x)+Cx+K$ and now I find K for $f(0)$? I ended up with K is 1-$\pi$.